# When do I need to use @Override, after implemented abstract method

Tags: java

```
public interface Game{
   public abstract boolean isValid(int coup);
}
```

```
public Machin implements Game{

   //Do I need to write @Override here ?
   public boolean isValid(int coup){
     //exemple
     if (coup==0){
        return false
     }
     return true
   }

}
```

I don't understand Overriding with abstract method could you help me ? Do I need to put @Override ?

Answer (score 0):

**Overriding** is when a subclass method is different than that of its superclass. Interfaces do not have method bodies - they solely force all classes that implement to have these functions. You do not need the override tag in the Machin class but if you were to create a subclass of with an isValid() method, you would need to override.

Comment: Okay thank's for help ^^

Comment: I wish to point out a couple things here. 1) The `@Override` annotation doesn't really do anything for most compilers, so it's mostly just a hint for the reader. The code will run just fine with or without the annotation. 2) Interfaces **can** have method bodies through the use of default implementations. 3) The `@Override` annotation can prevent you from doing stupid things, like messing with the method header.  For these reasons, I would recommend using the `@Override` annotation on the `isValid()` method to indicate that this is indeed overriding a method from the `Game` interface.

Comment: Oh thank's a lot it's more clear now